# Wireshark and length of data

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, wireshark

I used wireshark, under our protocol we send and receive 5 bytes in payload, even  wireshark say 5 bytes received , but show : 0000010001 : 10 digit.

How i read it?

Comment: It's not at all clear *where* it's showing that. A screenshot would help.

Comment: no mistake, i just questioned conceptual problem. 00 == 0?

Comment: It's impossible to answer a "conceptual problem" when you've said what's displayed, but without any context. We don't know what that's meant to represent at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) - each two digits correspond to one byte.

Comment: I modified it with bitwise operators.